# Use of Xil_Out32 in Xilinx SDK

Tags: fpga, xilinx, zynq, vivado

In Vivado I succesfully made a simple blockdiagram to control the LEDs of my Zybo board. I can observe that the offset address for my `LEDs is: 0x4120 0000` and the `High Address is 0x4120 FFFF`. Now when I go to the SDK:

```
#include <xil_printf.h>
#include <xil_types.h>
#include "platform.h"
#include "xgpio_l.h"

volatile u32 *LED_DATA = (u32 *) 0x41200000 ;   
int main()
{

    init_platform();

    xil_printf(" Writing to LEDs:   \n\r");
    Xil_Out32((&LED_DATA) + (0x00)  , 0xFFFFFFFF);     //All LEDs ON

    cleanup_platform();
    return 0;
}
```

I programmed the FPGA and run the above code. But still no success whatsoever.
Could someone point out my errors?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is to use `&LED_DATA`, which return the address of the pointer `LED_DATA`, not `0x41200000` as I think you expect.

Try

```
Xil_out32(0x41200000, 0xFFFFFFFF);
```

or

```
*LED_DATA = 0xFFFFFFFF;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jonathan. I already tried this but unfortunately it only results in hanging of the software.

Comment: Did you use the axi_gpio module to control your leds?

Comment: Yes I did, this is the reason for me asking. Normally it should work.

Comment: I tested the code I gave you, it works (on a microblaze, but still). If the system hangs, it's usually because the bus transfer never returns. Double-check your system, I suggest you use the defines in <xparameters.h> instead of manual address input.

Comment: I'll try the defines within <xparameters.h>, thanks anyway :)

Comment: I'm working on the same project. is there any reference or book for programming of microblaze in SDK environment?

Comment: Look for UG643. It has basic API reference as well as links to other interesting documents.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
#define ADDR 0x41200000 // write this before main() function.
```

Then you have to add the following line within main function.

```
Xil_Out32(ADDR + 0x00000000)  , 0xFFFFFFFF);     //All LEDs ON
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

This work

```
#define ADDRESS_GPIO_0   0x41200000     // vivado block diagram address editor

XGpioPs_Config * ConfigPtr1 = XGpioPs_LookupConfig(XPAR_PS7_GPIO_0_DEVICE_ID);
XGpioPs_CfgInitialize(&Gpio1, ConfigPtr1, ADDRESS_GPIO_0);
XGpioPs_SetDirection(&Gpio1, XGPIOPS_BANK0, 0x0F);
XGpioPs_Write(&Gpio1, XGPIOPS_BANK0, 0x0F);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for this post.  It helped me resolve a compile issue in sdk.   The issue was that the line below would not compile.

xil_printf("Wrote: 0x%08x \n\r", *(baseaddr_p+0));

I added this and it worked:

## include "xil_printf.h"

Thanks so much
Rajat Sewal